# URL rewriting in JSP

Tags: jsp, struts, netbeans-6.9

After Struts forwards the user to another page I get something like "http://localhost:8080/LiMS/login.do".  How do I get it to say "http://localhost:8080/LiMS/view/welcome.jsp"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forwarding happens at server-side, and the browser doesn't know about it. You could redirect to the JSP rather than forwarding, but the whole point of an MVC framework like Struts is to avoid accessing JSPs directly, and alway go through a front controller preparing the model for the view.

Why do you want to see welcome.jsp?